# Error: can't connect to new replica set master

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-atlas

I have been trying to connect my node js application to mongo db atlas but i keep getting this error

```
`MongoDB shell version v4.2.5
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-02-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017/test?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
2020-04-12T18:35:54.356-0700 I  NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-02-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017
2020-04-12T18:35:54.358-0700 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-02-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017
2020-04-12T18:35:54.359-0700 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-01-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017
2020-04-12T18:35:54.359-0700 I  CONNPOOL [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Connecting to cluster0-shard-00-00-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017
2020-04-12T18:35:56.232-0700 I  NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Confirmed replica set for Cluster0-shard-0 is Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017
2020-04-12T18:35:58.988-0700 I  NETWORK  [js] Marking host cluster0-shard-00-02-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017 as failed :: caused by :: Location40659: can't connect to new replica set master [cluster0-shard-00-02-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017], err: AuthenticationFailed: bad auth Authentication failed.


*** It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your IP whitelist allows connections from your network.


2020-04-12T18:35:58.991-0700 E  QUERY    [js] Error: can't connect to new replica set master [cluster0-shard-00-02-kmhdr.mongodb.net:27017], err: AuthenticationFailed: bad auth Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-04-12T18:35:59.025-0700 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-04-12T18:35:59.026-0700 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue.

- Check if your ip is whitelisted. Follow instructions here
  https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/whitelist-connection-ip-address/.
- Check your system/hosting is not blocking port 27017 and for testing of this port see instructions on http://portquiz.net:27017/

That's how i solved this.